# Errors when creating a Web service client in Java

Tags: java, asp.net, service, jax-ws

I've seen this problem all over the Web, but still haven't found a clear solution that has worked for me. Here's the issue:

I am trying to create a Web service client in Java.  The client needs to be a console app that will be placed on a server and automatically run at a certain time interval. The Web service I am trying to consume was written and is hosted by a third party company.  The service was written in ASP.NET.  The company in question has several services that we hit. All of them are written in ASP.NET. I have never dealt with these services until 2 days ago when I was tasked with consuming 2 of the services and building an Excel spreadsheet from the data.  Before I continue, let me describe my development environment.  Some of this is relevant, some is not, but I want to include everything:

- Windows 7 Professional 32-bit
- NetBeans IDE 6.9.1
- Java JDK 1.6.0_17
- jre6
- Glassfish 3 Open Source Full-Platform Release
- All software has had all available updates applied

On to the problem.  When I added the first Web Service Client to my console app, I was surprised at how smoothly the process went.  Most of my experience writing Web Service apps is in .NET.  I was able to import the WSDL and NetBeans generated all classes on the first try.  Within 5 minutes, I was able to make my first call to the service and was greeted with the expected response, letting me know that my attempt was successful. I then added the second Web Service Client to the console app using the address to the second WSDL I needed.  This is where I ran into a major problem.

Upon importing the WSDL, I was alerted to an error by NetBeans stating:

> Web Service Client can not be created by JAXWS:wsimport utility.
>   Reason:  undefined element declaration 's:schema'

After abusing Google for the next hour looking for a solution, I finally decided to apply some trial and error.  Looking at the Output window in NetBeans, I could see that it was complaining about 3 specific lines.  Once I took a look at the WSDL, I could see that those 3 lines were exactly the same, as follows:

```
<s:element ref="s:schema" />
```

These 3 lines were found in random places from the top of the WSDL, down to about half-way through.  I removed these lines from the WSDL found in the Web Service References folder, leaving the WSDL in the META-INF folder alone.  I then did a refresh on the service reference and much to my surprise, NetBeans parsed the WSDL and generated my classes just as before.  Great, right?  Well, here's where problem #2 comes into play.

Now that I was able to compile my app with no errors, I had to try to hit the service to see if my hack had worked.  It did not.  Because of another bug in JAXWS, I have to provide the URL to the WSDL in the constructor when creating a service object. This means that the WSDL I fixed is being ignored and the service is now back to using the WSDL that can not be parsed.  When I tried to provide the location of WSDL I edited locally within my project, I was greeted with another compilation error stating that I had a NullPointerException. It said that I needed to initialize the object before using it.

I have researched what seems like an infinite amount of topics on this site looking for and trying any solutions that have been provided. I have also tried solutions from all over the Web, all with no luck.  If anyone has any advice for me, any tips, tricks, hacks, please let me know. I'm open to any suggestions at this point.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/vivekp/archive/2007/05/how_to_deal_wit_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-sided contract changes may lead to problems.

Assuming the `s` prefix refers to the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace, it looks like your WSDL references XML schema types. JAX-WS is probably unable to resolve this when generating the JAXB bindings.

You can download the XSD from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.html; at a minimum, you'll need `XMLSchema.xsd`, `XMLSchema.dtd` and `datatypes.dtd`. Generating Java types from this may require fiddling with your JAXB binding configuration.

Alternatively, it may be easier to just use [dynamic JAX-WS client code](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_dynamic). You can use a tool like soapUI to create/test sample XML requests.

---

If you do decide to edit the WSDL, the generated service code should have a constructor of the form `Foo_Service(URL, QName)` that allows you to provision the WSDL locally (e.g. from your classpath).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is try to open it in one of the tools meant for testing SOAP services, like SoapUI. If you have schema not resolving, that is possible there will be pieces of code that you may need that won't be generated as well. I had that happen recently with a vendor supplied "web service", and after much dissembling they "miraculously" found an alternative set of services that worked fine.

You could also try some of the alternatives to Jax-Ws, like CXF or Axis.